# Adjoints functors.

Tags: category-theory

> Let G be a group.
>
> (a) What interesting functors are there between $\textbf{Set}$ and the category $[G,\textbf{Set}]$ of left $G$-sets? Which of those functor are adjoint to which.
>
> (b) Similarly, what interesting functors are there between $\textbf{Vect}_k$ and the category $[G,\textbf{Vect}_k]$ of $k$-linear representations of $G$, and what adjunctions are there between the functors?

I did (a) and I found that the functor $I:\textbf{Set}\rightarrow[G,\textbf{Set}]$ that gives to each set the trivial action has adjoints at each side.

These functors are:

- $\mathscr{O}:[G,\textbf{Set}]\rightarrow\textbf{Set}$ that sends each $G$-set to its orbit set.
- $\mathscr{F}:[G,\textbf{Set}]\rightarrow\textbf{Set}$ that sends each $G$-set to its set of invariants i.e  $a$ in the $G$-set such that for every $g\in G$ we have $ga=a$.

The relation $\mathscr{O}\dashv I \dashv \mathscr{F}$ holds.

Now, I do not know about $k$-linear representations, then I do not know about usual vector spaces that are related with a linear representation. I want to know about the functors between this categories, I can decide for myself what functor is adjoint to some of the others.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Everything you've said about the case of $\text{Set}$ can also be said about $\text{Vect}$.

Comment: Why does $\mathscr{O}$ sends $G$-vector space to  vector space?

Comment: The same question to $\mathscr{F}$. I could not prove it.

Comment: What I mean is the following. First of all, there is still a forgetful functor from $G$-vector spaces to vector spaces. This functor still has adjoints on both sides, given by taking invariants and coinvariants. But the forgetful functor from $\text{Vect}$ to $\text{Set}$ does not preserve colimits, so taking coinvariants in vector spaces looks different from taking coinvariants in sets.

Comment: Can you help just a little more? I mean, some clue to find those vector spaces. (I thought, kernel and cokernel but I do not know over what)

Comment: Hint: Find functors between $Set$ and $Vect_k$, and look up how adjoint functors work under composition.